# Android: neither onConnected, onConnectionSupspended or onConnectionFailedare being called

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I'm making a weather app and everything's working except for getting my user's location. I'm trying to do so with the play services API and calling getLongitude() and getLatitude(). However none of the code I'm writing is working because none of what I listed in the title is being run. Here's the code having to do with getting the location:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {
public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private CurrentWeather mCurrentWeather;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private double mLongitude;
private double mLatitude;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Location services connected.");
    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Location services suspended. Please reconnect.");

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Location services failed.");

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

Comment: in onConnectionSuspended try to reconnect with mGoogleApiClient.connect(); code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed initialize `GoogleApiClient` Object..

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

 mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

Please add above code and check.

Use this library in gradle. **com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0**

**Refer below link for getLocation.**

[Fused location provider example](http://kpbird.blogspot.in/2013/06/fused-location-provider-example.html)

Comment: Thanks for responding, but unfortunately that's not the issue. I actually did have those lines in my original code, I just forgot to put copy/paste them onto my post. I've edited the post and now it should be correct.

Comment: Don't write **mGoogleApiClient.connect();** everywhere, put only on one place

Comment: Which one place should I put it in? onStart, onResume or onCreate?

Comment: OnCreate is okey...also use this library in gradle. **com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0**

Comment: Make sure you are tesing in real device which have latest google play services.

Comment: Nevermind, I was wrong about what version of play services i was using. I was using an older one, and I updated to 8.4.0 and now it's working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The location returned inside onConnected() may be NULL. So u need to check that inside onConnected()

```
Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

if (location != null) {
    mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
}
```

Now it won't get location update again so you need to request location update as below -

create a location request object

```
protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}
```

You can call above method in onCreate() itself.

Now Add below code line to get the location updates in onConnected() method -

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

You can stop location updates once you get the user location by below code.

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I'm getting stuck in trying the create a location request object (your second step). Both UPDATE_INTERVAL and FASTEST_INTERVAL aren't recognized in android studio and causing errors. There's no quick fix. Is there something i need to import or do? thanks.

Comment: @Jake: My bad those r integer values. private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5000; // 5 sec
    private static int FATEST_INTERVAL = 1000; // 1 sec